# Does this usage of check-then-act of an AtomicInteger need to be synchronised?

Tags: java, multithreading, asynchronous, concurrency, synchronization

I have this loop that starts worker threads, that decrement an AtomicInteger when they are finished, and I have a check for starting a task when it gets to 0.

```
private static AtomicInteger dataReadings;

void someMethod() {
    dataReadings = new AtomicInteger(objects.size());
    for (Object object: objects)
            LongAction.perform(object).setResultCallback(new LongActionCallback<Object>() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(Object object) {
                    if (dataReadings.decrementAndGet() == 0) {
                        doSomething();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
}
```

So my question is should I synchronize the following part of the code:

```
if (dataReadings.decrementAndGet() == 0) {
    doSomething();
}
```

and if I should, how? Using a synchronized block? what should I synchronize on?

Comment: We can't really know what you want to achieve here, what objects is, which threads are doing what, etc. But If objects is modified concurrently by several threads, and you expect dataReadings to always become 0 when all objects have been processed, then your code is not thread-safe. Synchronizing the snippet of code you ask about won't make it more thread-safe, though.

Comment: You _do_ need to synchronized the assignment and reading of the `dataReadings` field, though (or possibly make it a local variable).

Comment: @JBNizet why isn't it thread safe? I expect dataReadings to always get to 0, yes. What should I do?

Comment: I can't answer that question without understanding what you want to achieve, what objects is, which threads are reading or modifying it, etc. But simple example: thread A initializes dataReadings to the size of objects: 10. Then thread B removes 5 items from objects. Then thread A starts iterating on those 5 objects. At the end, dataReadings value if 5, not 0. Note BTW that dataReadings has no reason to be a static field. It should be a local variable of the method. Otherwise two threads calling that method will step on each other's toes.

Comment: I dont think you need to synchronise AtomicInteger as it guarantees thread safety.

Answer (score 1):

The whole point of an `AtomicInteger` is that every single function in it is *atomic*, including `decrementAndGet()`.

You only need to lock if you use the `AtomicInteger` twice, because then it might change between the two calls.  (and you only need to lock if you care whether it changes)

Answer (score 1):

No. That is the entire point of using [`AtomicInteger`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html), you do not need to synchronize. The first (and only) sentence of the Javadoc for the [`java.util.concurrent.atomic` package](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/package-summary.html) says *a small toolkit of classes that support lock-free thread-safe programming on single variables.*